# PHP: Convert windows path to unix path

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to host a PHP website developed on a Mac on IIS.
I have an upload form for images. The path to the images is saved to the database in Windows style (i.e. \images\foo.jpeg). In my template I use these images as background using css. Because of the Windows-style paths the images are not displayed, cause the path is incorrect.

Question: How can I convert a Windows path to a valid URL. So \uploads\images\25.jpeg should be changed to /uploads/images/25.jpeg . Is there a function like realpath that can do this or should I take the dirty way using a str_replace or regex?

Comment: `str_replace` or you could just use `/` in the windows path.  Both `\\`` and `/` work in windows.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, I don't know about Mac, but Unix is also case sensitive, while Windows is not.

Comment: if they are already created, I guess str_replace wouldn't be a dirty way. If you wanna save them accordingly, I think you need to update your question. I guess there is a way to change how IIS behaves about paths that unfortunately I have no idea how. Good luck.

Comment: @AbraCadaver et al... in fact `/` worked in the pre-windows DOS days too; it was only `command.com` and later `cmd.exe` that didn't allow it because they use forward-slash to introduce command-line arguments. Generally, if you're doing anything with the web you should use `/` and not `\` no matter what platform you're using.

Comment: What kind of database? Most have built-in languages for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 4):

You convert all windows path to UNIX path using the following function. it's a WordPress core function and well tested

```
function wp_normalize_path( $path ) {
    $path = str_replace( '\\', '/', $path );
    $path = preg_replace( '|(?<=.)/+|', '/', $path );
    if ( ':' === substr( $path, 1, 1 ) ) {
        $path = ucfirst( $path );
    }
    return $path;
}
```

**Example :**

```
E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\php\\index.php
```

**Output :**

```
E:/xampp/htdocs/php/index.php
```

Comment: The up-to-date source code for this function is at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_normalize_path/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the **DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR** instead of the '/' or '\' for paths ([dir constants](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php)). This constant will recognize the OS for you and will use the right separator base on that.

To change the oldpath you can try to use:

```
str_replace("/", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 'example/bla/bla.php');
```

As tip: __FILE__, __DIR__ or dirname() can help you in lot of situations to get the right path on the running OS.